# Given a fine plate with DC current injected and drained by two punctual electrodes in the sides. Is the current density greater in the edges?

Tags: electromagnetism

Given a fine rectangular conducting plate (conductivity $\sigma$), with a constant current $I$ being injected and drained by electrodes at points $(0,b)$ and $(2a,b)$ respectively, what is the current distribution $\vec{J}$ in it?

[image: Proposed problem]

---

The solution I arrived at shows a stronger current density at the edges. I expected greater density in the middle of the plate. Is the result I got correct, or maybe there is something wrong with my solution?

[image: Current density]

### Method to arrive at the solution

It is considered that outside of the plate there is no conductivity, hence no current; also that all charges in the plate are free, i.e., 
$$\nabla \dot\ \vec J = 0$$
considering the plate isotropic: $$\vec J = \sigma \vec E$$
Thus $$\nabla \dot\ \vec E = 0$$
Also, given that the current is constant, there is no time-variant magnetic field, then the electric field is irrotational and can be expressed as the gradient of a scalar field (the electric potential)
$$\nabla \times \vec E = 0$$
$$\vec E = -\nabla u$$

From the null divergence, we have Laplace's equation for the potential (in two dimensions): $$\nabla^2 u = 0$$

Boundary conditions:
$$u(x,0) = 0$$
$$u(x,2b) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y) = \frac{I}{\sigma} \delta(y-b)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(2a,y) = \frac{I}{\sigma} \delta(y-b)$$

$\delta(y)$ is Dirac's delta

The solution is $$u(x,y) = \frac{I}{\sigma \, b} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}\, \sin(k_n\, y)}{\cosh(k_n\, 2a)} \frac{[-\sinh(k_n\, x) + \sinh(k_n\, (2a-x))]}{k_n}$$

Where
$$k_n = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2b}$$

Taking the gradient of $u$ and multiplying by $(-\sigma)$ yields the $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ parts of $\vec J$

$$\vec J \dot\ \vec x = \frac{I}{b} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}\, \sin(k_n\, y)}{\cosh(k_n\, 2a)} [-\cosh (k_n\, x) - \cosh (k_n\, (2a-x))]$$

$$\vec J \dot\ \vec y = \frac{I}{b} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}\, \cos(k_n\, y)}{\cosh(k_n\, 2a)} [-\sinh(k_n\, x) + \sinh(k_n\, (2a-x))]$$

I used the Python code below to get the quiver figure above.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

a = 8
b = 10
num_coefs = 70

def J5(x,y):
    I = 10
    valx = 0
    valy = 0
    for n in range(num_coefs):
        m = (2*n+1)
        c = m*np.pi/(2*b)
        B = np.cosh(c*2*a)
        valx += (-1)**m * np.sin(c*y)*(-np.cosh(c*x) - np.cosh(c*(2*a-x)))/B
        valy += (-1)**m * np.cos(c*y)*(-np.sinh(c*x) + np.sinh(c*(2*a-x)))/B

    return I/b*valx, I/b*valy

n5 = 20
x5 = np.linspace(0.1, 2*a-0.1, n5)
y5 = np.linspace(0.1, 2*b-0.1, n5)
X5, Y5 = np.meshgrid(x5, y5)

Jx, Jy = J5(X5,Y5)
plt.figure(5)
plt.quiver(x5, y5, Jx, Jy, angles='xy')#, scale=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are assuming that outside your conducting plate you have an insulator.
If that is so then your boundary conditions $u(x,0) = 0$ and $u(x,2b) = 0$ are incorrect.

I would have expected a potential gradient along those two surfaces and the electric field pattern to look something like that between two point charges.

Your current density diagram shows that current is flowing in the region surrounding the plate.

Comment: Why is it wrong, isn't the potential arbitrary? I've set my potential so that it is zero at the edges of my plate. Though I do have a potential outside my plate (assumed an insulator), it does not matter as I am only interested in the current on the plate. Anyway, I've reworked my solution and it seems I've made a mistake. I posted an answer...

Comment: @PedroH.N.Vieira Potential is certainly arbitrary but you are making the potential the same along those surfaces. Will it not change as one moves down the plate? If you look at the current (density) it looks as though some current is leaking through the sides which are insulated.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked my solution and realized that the $(-1)^{2n+1}$ in my equations should be $(-1)^{n}$, and also that I should reverse the sign of the whole equation.

$$u(x,y) = \frac{I}{\sigma \, b} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n}\, \sin(k_n\, y)}{\cosh(k_n\, 2a)} \frac{[\sinh(k_n\, x) - \sinh(k_n\, (2a-x))]}{k_n}$$

$$\vec J \dot\ \vec x = \frac{I}{b} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n}\, \sin(k_n\, y)}{\cosh(k_n\, 2a)} [\cosh (k_n\, x) + \cosh (k_n\, (2a-x))]$$

$$\vec J \dot\ \vec y = \frac{I}{b} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^{n}\, \cos(k_n\, y)}{\cosh(k_n\, 2a)} [\sinh(k_n\, x) - \sinh(k_n\, (2a-x))]$$

$$k_n = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2b}$$

The quiver plot now gives exactly what I expect.

[image: current distribution]